# How do I "capture" the part of the path matched by **

Tags: spring

I've got a @RequestMapping that looks like:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{bar}/blah/**")
public void handleRequest(@PathVariable String bar, @PathVariable String remainder) {
```

How do I configure things so that remainder gets whatever is matched by "**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Spring does support Ant style path patterns, they have not provided a way to return what was captured.

Fear not though, as this is something you can calculate yourself.  You can define your controller method to take in the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object.  From there, you are able to access the URI by calling [`getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) on the request object.

It will require some `String` processing, but that just sounds like more fun code to write.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that in the interests of cleanliness, but if there's no other way it won't be terribly difficult.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to have in the library.  It doesn't seem like something that would be too difficult to implement on Spring's side.  Perhaps they haven't thought of it, and only need a feature request...